# Como integrar o AngularJS com scripts comuns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Minha dúvida começou quando eu tentei usar o [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) do twitter bootstrap dentro de um projeto AngularJS, não funcionou de jeito nenhum.

Encontrei o [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), resolvi meu problema utilizando este componente, mas minhas dúvidas são as seguinte:

1 - Para cada coisa comum que eu queira utilizar no Angular eu terei que reescrever para que funcione na sintaxe do projeto? Por exemplo, no caso citado eu teria que reescrever o Carousel na sintaxe do Angular para poder utilizar?

2 - Criando um projeto AngularJS eu terei que utilizar apenas os plugins criados para esta plataforma? Como eu lido com códigos Javascript "comuns" ?

3 - Exemplo, eu quero usar OpenLayers em um projeto, eu teria que reescrever um plugin para que eu pudesse instanciar os objetos e funcionar no angular? como por exemplo esse [cara fez](http://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, respostas às suas perguntas:

1) **Não**. Porém é interessante que você saiba como o AngularJS funciona, evitando assim conflitos entre as maneiras como diferentes plugins JavaScript interagem entre si (assim como suas expectativas de ambiente).

Grande parte dos problemas encontrados por usuários utilizando o Twitter Carousel com AngularJS é devido à maneira como o Angular intercepta tags *Anchor* (`<A>`).

Este post do SO original explica bem este problema, e o usuário *rbanning* solucionou o problema sem usar o Angular Bootstrap UI:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907843/bootstrap-carousel-not-working-with-angularjs

2) **Não**. Eu tenho, por exemplo, soluções que misturam código nativo JavaScript, JQuery (base e UI), AngularJS, D3.JS... a lista continua. Contanto que você esteja atento à maneira como estes módulos/frameworks se comportam, integração não é problema.

3) **A escolha é sua**. Você pode incorporar seu conteúdo diretamente em um *controller*, implementar um serviço ou uma diretiva ou utilizar componentes já prontos. Este post (em inglês) descreve a tentativa bem-sucedida de um desenvolvedor para integrar AngularJS e OpenLayers:

http://siderite.blogspot.com/2013/10/openlayers-angularjs-add-features.html

AngularJS é um framework para desenvolvimento de aplicações, e possui características próprias no que tange à injeção de dependências, *binding* de objetos e escopo de dados. um estudo mais aprofundado pode lhe ajudar a identificar as razões pelas quais suas tentativas iniciais não foram bem-sucedidas.

Comment: +1 Sensacional sua resposta! Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo do AngularJS com D3.JS, por favor?

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway você diz um site que utiliza os dois? Eu implementei este aqui, que utiliza d3.js para o dendograma taxonômico: https://pubapps.bucknell.edu/mammalspecies/#/map/3170

Comment: Ficou lindo seu trabalho, @OnoSendai! Eu adorei de verdade, só que eu queria aprender também, por isso pedi um exemplo (esqueci de falar do exemplo com o código). De qualquer forma, obrigado. Foi inspirador!

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway Err desculpe, falta de café. =) Deixa eu preparar um pra você.

Answer (score 4):

O Angular tem basicamente 2 tipos de componentes que vc pode construir e usar:

1) Serviços e 2) Diretivas

Pra usar alguma outra coisa (digamos, um plugin JQuery) dentro de um projeto Angular, é necessário criar uma espécie de "wrapper angular" pra essa coisa, e aí vc usa esse "wrapper".
Esse wrapper, tem que ser um serviço ou uma diretiva.

Via de regra:
- se o que vc quer usar é simplesmente um objeto javascript, vc vai querer criar um Serviço
- se o que vc quer usar faz algum tipo de manipulação do DOM, vc vai querer criar uma diretiva.

Um exemplo de um serviço:
No minicurso [1] do ng-masters [2], veja os passos 8, e 9. No passo 9, eu crio um wrapper em volta do jquery.get() pra falar com um backend de mentirinha

Um exemplo de diretiva:
Nesse post [3], o Pedro Nauck ensina como criar uma diretiva "tooltip" que aplica uma tooltip Jquery num elemento qualquer.
Esse é o jeito "certo" de fazer isso com Angular (ao inves de botar um `$('.tooltip').tooltip()` no onload da pagina), porque isso continua funcionando mesmo em novos elementos "tooltipados" que venham a ser adicionados no DOM depois da página ter sido carregada.

- [1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gL0Hbk74i4&list=PLgMNBa0XaIgcD9IGiqvAQxPrUEyW_i87I&index=1
- [2] http://ng-masters.com
- [3] http://pedronauck.com/angularjs/sobre-diretivas-e-como-usar-corretamente-plugins-jquery-com-angularjs

Comment: Valeu Tony! Bastante esclarecedor, vou estudar mais a fundo o Angular, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O angular foi desenvolvido principalmente para testes. Você até pode inserir scripts fora do padrão angular, mas na hora dos testes você vai ter problema.

Mas seu caso é parecido com o meu. Quando desenvolvi meu projeto em angular fui instruido a usar o bootstrap e acabei me perguntando a mesma coisa. Por sorte, tem um pessoal que já reescreveu o bootstrap.js em angular:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Quanto ao OpenLayers, usar este projeto que você mandou o link não vai te atender do mesmo jeito que esse do boostrap acima?

Comment: Ian Luca, é que a questão é mais filosófica sabe, numa hipotética idéia de que algum dia eu necessite de uma biblioteca específica que alguém ainda não tenha escrito como vou proceder? A questão é sobre a flexibilidade do Angular em aceitar os padrões que não são relativos a sua sintaxe e fazer com que um código legado por exemplo funcione na infraestrutura do projeto, como citado no exemplo, o carousel do Bootstrap.

Comment: Aí você cria diretivas @PauloLuan, e é ideia de você utilizar scripts externos(plugins) juntamente com AngularJS